# Laravel Undefined Offset 0 Error Leading up to "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel handle"

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-route

I'm having a very hard problem seemly after make an multi-oauth configuration for admin and salesperson. But in fact, i really don't know what caused this problem. Because of it, i really appreciate your humbleness to help me on this one.

When tried to access this route :

> salesperson/transaction/create/manual (in salesperson pages)

or

> transaction/create/manual (in admin pages)

I'm getting Undefined offset 0 because i can't get the data that API provides. This error only occured after i reload page several times (maybe 2 or 3 times reload). And after i reload again, the error somehow fixed, and later.. it did happen again after pages reload :(

In the Laravel Bug Review, it shows that the error leading up to

> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel handle

Image [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldaII.png
[The file which get an error of undefined offset 0]

Image [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVFRS.png
[The file edge of the error]

For your consideration, i'm using Laravel 5.8.35. And this is the function in file named SalesPersonController.php which i get an undefined offset 0 error.

```
class SalesPersonController extends Controller
{   
use AuthorizesRequests, ValidatesRequests;

public function Index(){
    if(isset($id)){
        $search['value'] = $id;
        $search['type'] = "exact";
        $search['payment_type'] = $payment_type;
        $user = Myhelper::post('transaction/get_customer', $search);
        // return $user;
        if(isset($user['status'])&&($user['status']==='success')){
            $data['user'] = $user['result'];
        }else{
            $data['user'] = [];
        }
        // return $data['user'];

        if($data['user'] == []){

            $message = ['Customer '.$id.' tidak ditemukan'];
            session(['error'=> $message]);

            if (isset($payment_type) && $payment_type == 'manual') {
                return redirect('salesperson/transaction/create/manual');
            }else{
                return redirect('/transaction/create');
            }

        }elseif( isset($data['user']['transaction'] ) ){

            // && $data['user']['transaction'] !=[] && ($data['user']['transaction']['payment_type'] == 'manual' && $data['user']['transaction']['payment_status'] == 'success')
            $midtrans = false;
            $success = false;
            $receipt = '';

            foreach ($data['user']['transaction'] as $item) {

                if($item['payment_status'] == 'success'){
                    $receipt = $item['receipt_number'];
                    $success = true;
                    break;
                }elseif($item['payment_type'] == "midtrans"){
                    $midtrans = true;
                    $receipt = $item['receipt_number'];
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ($success) {
                $message = ['Transaksi untuk customer "'.$data['user']['name'].'" dengan email "'.$data['user']['email'].'" dan nomor "'.$data['user']['phone'].'" sudah terkonfirmasi'];
                session(['success'=> $message]);

                return redirect('/transaction/detail/'.$receipt);

            }elseif($midtrans){

                $message = ['Transaksi untuk customer "'.$data['user']['name'].'" dengan email "'.$data['user']['email'].'" dan nomor "'.$data['user']['phone'].'" sudah menggunakan pembayaran midtrans'];
                session(['error'=> $message]);

                return redirect('/transaction/detail/'.$receipt);                    
            }

        }
        // return $user;

    }else{
        $request = [
            'bank' => 1,
            'bank_method' => 1,
            'manual_payment' => 1,
            'city' => 1,
            'price' => 1,
            'today' => 1,
            'salesperson' => 1
        ];
        $data = MyHelper::post('transaction/get_master_data', $request);
    }

    $product = MyHelper::get('product');
    $all_product = MyHelper::get('product/all');
    // dd($product['status']);
    if((isset($product['status'])&&($product['status'] ==='success')) && (isset($all_product['status'])&&($all_product['status'] ==='success'))){
        $data['product'] = $product['result'];
        $data['all_product'] =  $all_product['result'];
    }else{
        $data['product']= [];
        $data['all_product'] = [];
    }
    // dd($data['product']);
    // dd($data['all_product']);

    $enumProduct = MyHelper::get('product/get_enum_data');
    if(isset($enumProduct['status']) && ($enumProduct['status']==='success')){
        $data['enum_product'] = $enumProduct['result'];
    }else{
        $data['enum_product'] = [];
    }
    //  dd($data['enum_product']);exit;

    $data['aligner'] = [];
    $data['aligner_2'] = [];
    $data['non_aligner'] = [];
    $data['full_aligner'] = [];
    $data['full_aligner_2'] = [];

    $count1 = 0; $count2 = 0; $count3 = 0; $count4 = 0; $count5 = 0;
    foreach($data['all_product'] as $product2){
        if($product2['tipe'] === $data['enum_product']['tipe'][0]){
            $data['aligner'][$count1] = $product2;
            $count1++;
        }else if($product2['tipe'] === $data['enum_product']['tipe'][1]){
            $data['aligner_2'][$count2] = $product2;
            $count2++;
        }else if($product2['tipe'] === $data['enum_product']['tipe'][2]){
            $data['non_aligner'][$count3] = $product2;
            $count3++;
        }else if($product2['tipe'] === $data['enum_product']['tipe'][3]){
            $data['full_aligner'][$count4] = $product2;
            $count4++;
        }else{
            $data['full_aligner_2'][$count5] = $product2;
            $count5++;
        }
    }

    $data['subtotal_service']['aligner'] = $this->getSubTotalService($data['aligner'][0]['id_product'], 'default');
    $data['subtotal_service']['aligner_2'] = $this->getSubTotalService($data['aligner_2'][0]['id_product'], 'default');
    $data['subtotal_service']['non_aligner'] = $this->getSubTotalService($data['non_aligner'][0]['id_product'], 'default');
    $data['subtotal_service']['full_aligner'] = $this->getSubTotalService($data['full_aligner'][0]['id_product'], 'default');
    $data['subtotal_service']['full_aligner_2'] = $this->getSubTotalService($data['full_aligner_2'][0]['id_product'], 'default');

    $data['default_harga'] = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['full_aligner']); $i++){
        $data['default_harga'] = $data['default_harga'] + $data['full_aligner'][$i]['harga'];
        $data['default_ppn_status'] = $data['full_aligner'][$i]['ppn_status'];
    }
    $data['default_product'] = $data['enum_product']['tipe'][3];

    $data['default_harga_2'] = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['full_aligner_2']); $i++){
        $data['default_harga_2'] = $data['default_harga_2'] + $data['full_aligner_2'][$i]['harga'];
        $data['default_ppn_status_2'] = $data['full_aligner_2'][$i]['ppn_status'];
    }
    $data['default_product_2'] = $data['enum_product']['tipe'][4];


    $data['date'] = Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data['payment_type'] = "manual";
    if (isset($data['today'])) {
        $data['today'] = date('d/M/Y',strtotime($data['today']));
    }

    return view('transaction::create_transaction2', $data);
}
```

And last, here is my routes in web.php (Backend View) and api.php (API)

```
<?php


 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Web Routes
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

Route::group(['middleware'=>'validate_session', 'prefix'=>'transaction'], function() {

    Route::get('tests/{type}/{receipt}', 'TransactionController@tests');
    Route::get('getSubTotalService/{product}','TransactionController@getSubTotalService'); Route::get('getTransactionParent/{prd_type}/{user_phone}/{email}','TransactionController@getTransactionParent');
    Route::get('getAlignerCicilan/{user_phone}','TransactionController@getAlignerCicilan');
    Route::get('getDiscount/{id_transaction}','TransactionController@getDiscount');
    Route::get('getProduct/{product_code}','TransactionController@getProduct');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['validate_session']], function(){

        Route::middleware('feature_control:18')->get('create/manual/{id}', ['uses' => 'TransactionController@create', 'payment_type' => 'manual']);
        Route::middleware('feature_control:18')->get('create/manual', ['uses' => 'TransactionController@create', 'payment_type' => 'manual']);
        Route::middleware('feature_control:18')->get('create/{id}', ['uses' => 'TransactionController@create', 'payment_type' => 'midtrans']);
        Route::middleware('feature_control:18')->get('create', ['uses' => 'TransactionController@create', 'payment_type' => 'midtrans']);
    });
});

Route::group(['middleware'=>'sales_person', 'prefix'=>'salesperson/transaction'], function(){
   Route::get('getSubTotalService/{product}','TransactionController@getSubTotalService');Route::get('getTransactionParent/{prd_type}/{user_phone}/{email}','TransactionController@getTransacti onParent');
   Route::get('getAlignerCicilan/{user_phone}','TransactionController@getAlignerCicilan');
   Route::get('getDiscount/{id_transaction}','TransactionController@getDiscount');
   Route::get('getProduct/{product_code}','TransactionController@getProduct');
   Route::post('getPromo', 'TransactionController@getPromo');
 });
```

The API routes

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Route::group(['prefix' => 'transaction'], function () { 
    Route::get('getAlignerCicilan/{user_phone}','TransactionController@getAlignerCicilan');
    Route::get('getDiscount/{id_transaction}','TransactionController@getDiscount');
    Route::get('getProduct/{product_code}','TransactionController@getProduct')
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/transaction', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'transaction', 'middleware' => 'auth:api' ], function () {

   Route::post('update/{id}','TransactionController@update');
   Route::get('edit/{receipt}','TransactionController@edit');
   Route::get('detail/{receipt}','TransactionController@detail');
   Route::get('delete/{receipt}','TransactionController@delete');
   Route::get('show/{id}','TransactionController@show');
   Route::get('/Report','DailyController@daily_report');

   Route::post('confirm_transaction','TransactionController@confirm_transaction');
   Route::post('storeApiTransactionManual','ApiTransactionManualController@store');
   Route::post('update_shipping','TransactionController@update_shipping');
   Route::post('store_transaction_user','TransactionController@store_transaction_user');
   Route::post('upload_images','TransactionController@upload_images');
   Route::post('delete_images','TransactionController@delete_images');
   Route::post('update_note','TransactionController@update_note');
   Route::post('update_aligner','TransactionController@update_aligner');
   Route::post('send_video_notification','TransactionController@send_video_notification');
   Route::post('confirm_complete','TransactionController@confirm_complete');
   Route::post('update_contact','TransactionController@update_contact');

});


Route::group(['prefix' => 'transaction'], function () {

   Route::post('store','TransactionController@store');
   Route::post('storeOrder','TransactionController@storeOrder');
   Route::get('getPromo/{code}/{id_product}','TransactionController@getPromoByCode');
   Route::get('get_default_product','TransactionController@getDefaultProduct');
   Route::post('get_master_data','TransactionController@post_master_data');
   Route::get('getPrice','TransactionController@getPrice');
   Route::get('getPrice/{product_slug}','TransactionController@getPriceProduct');
   Route::post('orderConfirm','TransactionController@orderConfirm');
   Route::post('notification','TransactionController@midtransNotif')->middleware('log_request');
   Route::get('test','TransactionController@test');
   Route::get('midtrans/{id_transaction}','TransactionController@midtrans_token')- >middleware('log_request');
   Route::get('kredivo/{receipt_number}','TransactionController@kredivo_token');
   Route::get('payment/{receipt_number}','TransactionController@midtrans_link');

   Route::get('getBank','ApiTransactionManualController@getBank');
   Route::get('getBankMethod','ApiTransactionManualController@getBankMethod');
   Route::get('getManualPayment','ApiTransactionManualController@getManualPayment');
   Route::post('storeTransactionManual','ApiTransactionManualController@store');
   Route::post('emailCheck','ApiTransactionManualController@emailCheck');
   Route::post('getUserEmail','ApiTransactionManualController@getUserEmail');
   Route::post('getUserEmailbyOrderId','ApiTransactionManualController@getUserEmailByOrderId');
   Route::post('storeBook/','ApiTransactionManualController@storeBook');
   Route::post('get_customer','TransactionController@get_customer');
   Route::get('get_waiting_counter','TransactionController@get_waiting_counter');


});

Route::group(['prefix'=>'salesperson', 'middleware'=>'auth:salesperson'],function(){
  Route::post('transaction/store_transaction_user','TransactionController@store_transaction_user');
});
```